# How to determine time it takes to call a function x number of times

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm working on function that determines the time it takes to run another function so I can see how long my code takes to run.

Here is the code:

```
public function profileCall(repeatCount:int, method:Function, ...args):String {
    var time:int = getTimer(); // returns time in milliseconds since app start
    var average:Number;

    for (var i:int; i < repeatCount; i++) {
        method.apply(null, args);
    }

    time = getTimer()-time;
    average = repeatCount>0? time/repeatCount:0;

    return average;
}

var result:String = profileCall(myCode, 1000);
trace("Time taken: " + result); // Time taken: .01
```

I thought it was working but then I noticed in one test if I run it 100 times it says 0.1. If I run it 1000 it says .01, at 10000 it says .001.

Is it getting more accurate or is there a miscalculation? I know on multiple calls the CPU will cache calls and that can decrease execution time but the numbers don't look right. Forgive me if this is a basic question, it has been a long day.

Note: The language does not matter.

Comment: nothing to do with Java

Comment: If I am not mistaken, shouldn't `getTimer()-time`, be `getTimer()->time`?

Comment: @Caelan. doesn't look right

Comment: nothing to do with javascript either ... it looks all actionscript

Comment: What is `name`? I don't see it being used inside the function. I expect the signature to be `public function profileCall(repeatCount:int, method:Function, ...args):Number` instead, so you only send in the number and function data. Also check if your function is really slow enough to be worth of profiling.

Comment: `Name` is used in the original function used to trace to the console. I took it out for the example code. I'll update the post.

Comment: The language doesn't matter.  I should have mentioned that in the question details.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, however... AS3 is not that slow so in most cases

```
var aTime:int = getTimer();

// ... do something

trace(getTimer() - aTime);
```

will take 0 to 1 milliseconds due to low precision of this operation. In order to evaluate the performance of certain code block you might need to run it in a loop of 1 000 000  or even 10 000 000 iterations and measure the **whole** execution time.

Comment: So if the value returned is zero then I need to repeat more times? Is it possible it would get more accurate the more iterations?

Comment: Exactly. Much more times.